# sidr menu close not working in chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mobile, sidr

I am using sidr as side menu for my website. But when I open it in chrome browser at my phone. It opens when I click the button. But doesn't close when I click the button again.
If I use the dolphin browser, it just works fine.

I've created a Fiddle.. This is my code which opens and closes the menu perfectly, doesn't seem  to work here.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8z0pjyz/)

JS:

```
$('#responsive-menu-button').sidr({
    name: 'sidr',
    source: '#menu',
    side: 'left'
});
```

CSS:

```
#mobile-header {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 0;
}
#mobile-header #responsive-menu-button {
    height: 41px;
    width: 42px;
    display:block;
}
#menu {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mobile-header"> <a id="responsive-menu-button" href="#menu">THE MENU</a>

</div>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="menu first" href="#first">First</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu second" href="#second"> Second</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu third" href="#third">third</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu fourth" href="#fourth">fourth</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also my viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is okay. Additional JavaScript for open/close needed, as you know. This works in web and mobile versions of Google Chrome.

```
<script src="http://yoursite.domain.../jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery('#responsive-menu-button').sidr({
name: 'sidr-main',
source: '.menu-main-nav-container'
});

jQuery( window ).load(function() {
if(jQuery("#sidr-main").length !== 0) {        
    jQuery(".sidr-class-sub-menu").hide();      
    jQuery( "li.sidr-class-menu-item ul.sidr-class-sub-menu" ).each(function() {
    jQuery( this ).after("<div class='lnk-plus'>+</div>");
    });

    jQuery( ".lnk-plus" ).toggle(function() {
        var id1= jQuery( this ).parent().attr("id");
        jQuery("#" + id1 + " ul.sidr-class-sub-menu").show();
        jQuery("#" + id1 + " .sidr-class-menu-item-has-children ul").hide();   
        jQuery( this ).html("-");
        }, function() {
        var id1= jQuery( this ).parent().attr("id");
        jQuery("#" + id1 + " ul.sidr-class-sub-menu").hide();
        jQuery( this ).html("+");
        });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Please notice where `jQuery(".sidr-class-sub-menu").hide();` is situated.